# How i can get the class that inherits QTreeView from current tab of QTabWidget?

Tags: c++, qt5, qtreeview, qtabwidget

I write a simple fm with tabs. I need put and get the class what inherits QTreeView thats named "View", from current tab in QTreeWidget.

i've tried

```
View v = qobject_cast<View>(ui->tabs->widget(index));
```

but this code return

```
error: use of deleted function ‘View::View(View&&)’
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent),
        ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
        View *view = new View;
        view->text = "hey";
        ui->tabs->addTab(view, "new");

        connect(ui->tabs, &QTabWidget::currentChanged, this, &MainWindow::curChanged);
}

void MainWindow::curChanged(int index)
{
        View v = qobject_cast<View>(ui->tabs->widget(index));
        // some code with View
}


MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
  delete ui;
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include "view.h"
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDebug>

namespace Ui {
  class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
  ~MainWindow();
  void curChanged(int index);

private slots:

private:
  Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

view.h

```
#include <QTreeView>
#include <QFileSystemModel>
#include <string.h>

class View : public QTreeView
{
        public:
                std::string text;
};
```

error message:

```
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I. -isystem /usr/include/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -I. -I/usr/lib64/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o main.o main.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I. -isystem /usr/include/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -I. -I/usr/lib64/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o mainwindow.o mainwindow.cpp
/usr/lib64/qt5/bin/moc -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB --include /home/c63/Projects/C++/QT/sof/moc_predefs.h -I/usr/lib64/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I/home/c63/Projects/C++/QT/sof -I/home/c63/Projects/C++/QT/sof -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -I/usr/include/qt5/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/include/g++-v8 -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/include/g++-v8/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/include/g++-v8/backward -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/include -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/include-fixed -I/usr/include mainwindow.h -o moc_mainwindow.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I. -isystem /usr/include/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -I. -I/usr/lib64/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o moc_mainwindow.o moc_mainwindow.cpp
g++ -Wl,-O1 -o sof main.o mainwindow.o moc_mainwindow.o   -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core /usr/lib64/libGLESv2.so -lpthread
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: mainwindow.o: in function `MainWindow::curChanged(int)':
mainwindow.cpp:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `View::staticMetaObject'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: mainwindow.o: in function `MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*)':
mainwindow.cpp:(.text+0x3aa): undefined reference to `vtable for View'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:171: sof] Error 1
```

Comment: change to `View *v = qobject_cast<View*>(ui->tabs->widget(index));`

Comment: @eyllanesc big thank you, but i have error: "error: cannot convert from pointer to base class ‘QObject’ to pointer to derived class ‘View’ via virtual base ‘QTreeView’"

Comment: Your `View` class must make use of the [`Q_OBJECT`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#qobject_cast) macro to enable its use with `qobject_cast`.

Comment: @G.M. i don't public this, but my class alredy have Q_OBJECT

Comment: Then please edit your question to show the *real* class definition for `View`.  Do you really inherit virtually from `QTreeView` as the error message seems to suggest?

Comment: @G.M. no i inherit like in example